# Google maps route matching

Tags: google-maps

I need to find out if 2 people are taking the same route to travel from city A to city B. Google maps returns multiple routes to travel from city A to city B. I am allowing users to mark waypoints to select a particular route. But in some cases, even if the routes are the same, if the selected waypoint is not present in the route array it does not match the same route. Is waypoints the right thing to do?

Comment: did you find a better way to deal this situation?

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using google maps "Legs". And comparing each using lists.

[image]